# Ошибка bcdiv(): Argument #1 ($num1) is not well-formed

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста пофиксить данную ошибку

Данные приходят с внешнего `api` в `float` формате, цель сделать из `float` строку и обрезать в конце нули (чтобы также прогонять подобные строки `'0.5450000' => '0.545'`)

```
<?php
function to_string($value, $fix = 12) {
    $string = bcdiv($value, 1, $fix);
    return $string = $fix > 0 ? rtrim(rtrim($string, '0'), '.') : $string;
}

$result = to_string(1.5);
echo gettype($result) .' '. $result; // string 1.5

$result = to_string(1.0E-6); // Ошибка bcdiv(): Argument #1 ($num1) is not well-formed
echo gettype($result) .' '. $result;
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/8a22f

Comment: Читали ли вы документацию по функици bcdiv? Знаете ли, какой формат она принимает у каждого параметра?

Comment: @Алексей, читал, параметры принимает как строки, я могу ему дать только float число, а результат нужен в виде строки

Comment: В PHP можно приводить типы.... как и в любом другом языке ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `number_format`

```
<?php
    function to_string($value, $fix = 12) {
        $string = bcdiv(number_format($value), 1, $fix);
        return $string = $fix > 0 ? rtrim(rtrim($string, '0'), '.') : $string;
    }
    
    $result = to_string(1.5);
    echo gettype($result) .' '. $result;
    
    $result = to_string(1.0E-6);
    echo gettype($result) .' '. $result;
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо, там только нужно было прописать `number_format($value, $fix, '.', '')`